# Need help installing mtpro2

Tags: pdftex, mtpro

I have texlive running on ubuntu 14.04lts. I am able to compile tex documents to pdf, except some documents which require use of mtpro2. After reading some instructions on how to instal mtpro2 here:

```
http://cims.nyu.edu/~fennell/mtpro2/
```

I removed the whole textlive installation , including the texmf folder in /usr/share. After reinstalling

```
 install-tl-unx.tar.gz
```

with

```
sudo ./install-tl
```

the installation went well and works fine.
However with soe files I get the mtpro2 file error below:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mtpro2.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
Enter file name:
```

Part of the output of running

```
./mtpro2-texlive.sh -i mtp2lite.zip.tpm
```

is below

```
Removing previous MTPro2 files, as a precaution.
Removing MTPro2 files from /usr/local/share/texmf.
Coping all files in ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_P9fTSILi/texmf/ to /usr/local/share/texmf/
Removing the temporary directory.
Updating TeX Live
...
```

Essentially the error appearing on the command line is:

```
chmod: cannot access ‘/usr/local/share/texmf/’: No such file or directory
```

How do I get back texmf in /usr/local/share?
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the directory `/usr/local/share/texmf/` exist?  If yes, what are the rights?

Comment: I removed the directory texmf from /usr/local/share/, so currently it does not exist.

Comment: 1. Get a working TeX-installation, independently from mtpro2. \\ 2. Buy the fonts and download them into your home directory or download the free fonts into your home folder. \\ 3. Proceed as described here: http://cims.nyu.edu/~fennell/mtpro2/ , starting with the sentence: »Now open a terminal....«. The installer will install the fonts into ~/texmf , which should work. If not, please edit your question, but don't mix installing TeX with installing mtpro2 -- and sorry, if I misunderstood your question and comment.

Comment: Just to clarify that TeX works ok. The problem is when I have to call fonts involving mtpro2. Installation of mt2prolite as given at http://cims.nyu.edu/~fennell/mtpro2/ does not work because I removed the texmf folder in /usr/local/share.

Comment: Thanks @Keks Dose and also to Jarauh and all who read my post. I mamanged to get things working, here's how: I have texlive working on Windows 7 on which I had installed a texmf directory in the root. I copied that directory into /usr/local/share on ubuntu. The installation of mtpro2 worked exactly as given in the cims.nyu.edu link. Thanks for time and effort.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba Yes, installing fonts still is kind of an adventure. I'm happy to read that you suceeded!